# Database design/Rails - design of balance between two users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relational-database

I am looking for a way of designing a Balance model between two users in Ruby on Rails (but could be more general). Two users Alice and Bob would start with a balance of value zero with regards to the other one. Now, if Alice gets a +4, I want Bob to have -4. Here's what I came up with so far:

- A balance with three fields : user_one, user_two, and one_to_two. That is if I want the balance for user_one to user_two I just take one_to_two, and if I want from two_to_one I take -one_to_two (just a method in the balance model). The problem is that I could not simply use 'has_many balances through' from the User model, since the balance would need to know if it's user_one or user_two who is calling (I would have to pass the User)
- A balance with three fields again, but completely asymmetric: if I create a balance for Alice to Bob, I would have to create another instance of balance from Bob to Alice. This would double the storage needed for each 'balance' in the database, and would require updating the bob_to_alice everytime I update alice_to_bob.

Can anyone come up with something better, or explain the reason for choosing one of the above? Let me know if I can make anything clearer.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I found something pretty neat. It uses the fact that user alice is always the one with the smallest id (via :ensure_alice_before_bob). The rest should be clear.

The User model just has two extra "has_many :balances_as_alice, has_many :balances_as_bob". It could work with only one (for instance :balances_as_alice), but with those two present + dependent: :destroy you make sure to avoid orphan balances.

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: balances
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  alice_id    :integer          not null
#  bob_id      :integer          not null
#  alice_value :float            default("0.0")
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#

class Balance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :alice, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :bob, class_name: 'User'
  before_validation :ensure_alice_before_bob
  validates :alice_id, presence: true
  validates :bob_id, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :alice_id}
  validate  :different_users

  def value
    @for_bob ? -alice_value : alice_value
  end

  def value=(new_val)
    @for_bob? self.alice_value = -new_val : self.alice_value = new_val
  end

  def Balance.get_for alice, bob
    user = 'alice'
    alice, bob, user = bob, alice, 'bob' if alice.id > bob.id
    balance= alice.balances_as_alice.find_by(bob: bob) || 
      Balance.new(bob: bob, alice: alice, alice_value: 0.0)
    balance.send("for_#{user}")
  end

  def for_bob
    @for_bob = true; self
  end

  def for_alice
    @for_bob = false; self
  end

  private
  def ensure_alice_before_bob
    return if self.alice_id.nil? || self.bob_id.nil?
    unless self.alice_id < self.bob_id
      self.bob_id, self.alice_id = self.alice_id, self.bob_id
    end
  end

  def different_users
    if self.alice_id == self.bob_id
      errors.add(:bob_id, "Cannot be the same user")
    end
  end
end
```